# How to transparently shade alternate days on a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vectorization, alpha-transparency, occlusion

What am I doing wrong here please?
I'm trying to shade alternate 24-hr daily rectangles with transparent gray. But only the last rectangle from the for-loop gets drawn(?!?) If I do things manually instead of by for-loop it works fine.

Is there a way to vectorize this to avoid the for-loop?
(And can it be done with qplot?)
I'm new to ggplot2 and yes I read through Hadley's site, book and examples.

Second issue: the alpha setting on the aesthetic doesn't prevent the rectangles occluding the background. How to get transparency?

```
dat <- data.frame(my_x_series=1:192, my_y_series=5.0*runif(192))
# (ymin, ymax are computed for this series using min/max(na.rm==TRUE))
ymax <- 5.0
ymin <- 0.0
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=my_x_series,alpha=0.9)) 
alternate_daily_bars_xmin <- c(4,52,100,148)

for (shade_xmin in alternate_daily_bars_xmin) {
    shade_xmax <- min(shade_xmin+24, 192) # clamp at end of x-range
    p <- p + geom_rect(aes(alpha=0.5,xmin=shade_xmin,xmax=shade_xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax), fill='gray80')
}
p <- p + geom_point(aes(y=my_y_series))
p
```

Comment: Added random definition of *dat* for reproducibility. It's the command syntax that's beating me. I guess each geom_rect overrides the last instead of compositing like you might expect.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To plot your rectangles, create a data frame where each row contains the coordinates for  a single rectangle. This construct works for all polygons, not just rectangles. Once you know this, it's easy to avoid the loop.

Then, just be careful whether you map a variable to an aesthetic or not. In your case, you need to set `alpha` to whatever value you wish, so it does not form part of the `aes()` settings.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(my_x_series=1:192, my_y_series=5.0*runif(192))
rect_left <- c(4,52,100,148)
rectangles <- data.frame(
  xmin = rect_left,
  xmax = rect_left + 24,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 5
)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data=rectangles, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), 
            fill='gray80', alpha=0.8) +
  geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=my_x_series, y=my_y_series))
```

[image]

Comment: Most probably all of it, but I've never bothered with `qplot`. `ggplot` is not really harder to learn, and you always know exactly what you will get. Sorry.