# Problem with geom_rect/ annotate("rec") cause a shift in the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, rstudio

I have a faceted graph, and all I want to do is have each facet with a different area of the background shaded- Here's the graph:

[image]

With both geom_rect and annotate("rect") when I try to plot different coordinates/ facet they just overlap on all of them like this:

[image]

or cause the data to shift left and makes a massive gap on the x-axis where it places the rectangle like this:

[image]

I have tried using a dataframe for both however this causes the shift in the graph too, and have tried all the suggested things I can find but with no luck, am hoping its a simple problem with the code.

Help to either of these would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much in advance!

My base code for the geom_rect graph is as follows;

```
rm(list=ls())
library("ggplot2")
data<- read.csv("circadian_time_n8.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")
head(data)
as.data.frame(data)
data$id<-factor(data$id)
data$binary<-factor(data$binary)

ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(time), y=factor(binary)),fill="black")+
      geom_bar(stat='identity')+
      facet_wrap(~id,  ncol=1,strip.position = "right")+
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = "2000", xmax = "2400", ymin = 0, ymax = 2),
                fill = "pink", alpha = 0.03)+
      scale_y_discrete(limits = c(0,2), breaks=c(0,1,2), label=c("Inactive", "walk", "run"))+
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(1600,3200,100),
                       label=c("16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00","21:00", "22:00", "23:00","00:00", "01:00","02:00", "03:00","04:00", "05:00",    "06:00",    "07:00", "08:00"))+
      labs(x="Time", y="Activity level")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(panel.border = element_blank())+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 1))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

and for annotate("rect")

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(time), y=factor(binary)),fill="black")+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  facet_wrap(~id,  ncol=1,strip.position = "right")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c(0,2), breaks=c(0,1,2), label=c("Inactive", "walk", "run"))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(1600,3200,100),
                   label=c("16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00","21:00", "22:00", "23:00","00:00", "01:00","02:00", "03:00","04:00", "05:00",    "06:00",    "07:00", "08:00"))+
  labs(x="Time", y="Activity level")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  annotate("rect", xmin = "1930", xmax = "3030", ymin = 0,  ymax = 2,alpha=.2)
```

The dataframe that I have tried is formatted the same as suggested in this answer; [Different geom_rect() objects for facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286629/different-geom-rect-objects-for-facets)

data;

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   8153 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X24hr   : Factor w/ 2046 levels "00:00:00","00:01:00",..: 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 ...
 $ id      : Factor w/ 8 levels "231","235","236",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ bark    : num  29.3 35.3 18.7 20.7 11.5 ...
 $ activity: Factor w/ 3 levels "high activity",..: 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ binary  : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ time    : int  1600 1601 1602 1603 1604 1605 1606 1607 1608 1609 ...
```

shorter version of data because the data set is too large for here;

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(X24hr = structure(c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"08:00:00", "09:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    id = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("231", 
    "235", "236", "237", "263", "267", "269"), class = "factor"), 
    bark = c(29.2727, 10.5455, 0.3636, 2.5455, 0, 0, 0, 0.1818, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1.4545, 8.3636, 11.8182, 0.7273, 6.7273, 
    1.6364, 0.1818, 0, 0, 0, 12.1818, 0.1818, 0, 1.0909, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.1818, 0, 2.1818, 12.1818, 0, 6.7273, 0, 0, 0, 11.4545, 
    0.3636, 0, 0, 0.7273, 4.1818, 19.0909, 4, 2.1818, 0, 0.1818, 
    4.5455, 5.2727, 9.4545, 50.5455, 10.1818, 9.2727, 0.7273, 
    0, 0.3636, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1818, 0.5455, 0, 42.3636, 0, 0.1818, 
    13.0909, 43.0909, 0, 3.8182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2727, 0.5455, 
    0, 0.3636, 0, 3.0909, 0, 10.1818, 2, 5.2727, 2, 29.2727, 
    15.2727, 8.3636, 1.8182, 0, 5.4545, 0, 3.2727, 0.3636, 1.6364, 
    1.2727, 2.9091, 0.3636, 0, 0, 0, 1.4545, 6, 10.3636, 42.9091, 
    4.7273, 0, 0, 0, 16, 12.5455, 4.5455, 0.1818, 1.0909, 0, 
    0, 5.2727, 12.5455, 2.5455, 5.2727), activity = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("high activity", "inactive", 
    "low activity"), class = "factor"), binary = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c(1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L, 3300L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L, 3300L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L, 3300L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L, 3300L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L, 3300L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L, 3300L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2100L, 2200L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2500L, 2600L, 2700L, 2800L, 2900L, 3000L, 3100L, 
    3200L)), row.names = c(NA, -125L), class = "data.frame")

> str(data)
'data.frame':   125 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X24hr   : Factor w/ 18 levels "00:00:00","01:00:00",..: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 1 2 ...
 $ id      : Factor w/ 7 levels "231","235","236",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ bark    : num  29.273 10.546 0.364 2.546 0 ...
 $ activity: Factor w/ 3 levels "high activity",..: 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
 $ binary  : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ time    : int  1600 1700 1800 1900 2000 2100 2200 2300 2400 2500 ...
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I was having this exact same problem with an `x` variable called `timepoint` in the shape of `"2020-07-14 00:00:21 UTC"` and my `annotate()` command was causing trouble until I forcefully identified the timezone as `tz="UTC"` in  `annotate("rect", xmin = as.POSIXct("2020-07-14 00:00:01 UTC", tz = "UTC"),
xmax = as.POSIXct("2020-07-14 07:00:00 UTC", tz = "UTC"), ...`