# Alternate background colour by date in x axis (e.g. by month)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a series of daily data for several years

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2020-01-01'), to = as.Date('2020-12-31'), by = 'day'),
                 value = runif(366))
```

I'd like to have the background colour to change every month, alternating from white to light grey. I've tried using `ifelse` inside `theme` but it did not work (apparently it takes the result for the first line and repeats along the whole plot).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value))+
    geom_line()+
    scale_x_date(breaks = 'month', expand = c(0,0))+
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(ifelse(lubridate::month(df$date) %% 2 == 0, 'white', 'grey')))
```

Comment: I've seen folks make rectangles in `geom_rect()` to do this like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565733/2461552)

Comment: That's a solution. although not what I wanted haha! Thanks!

Comment: I am also trying to do this, basically alternating between white and light grey for each month but I have to plot for each individual and their starting and ending values are different. I can't find anything that is flexible to handle this and have been looking for several hours!